# gcc:g++ being bureaucratic with template template friends

Tags: gcc, c++11, friend, crtp, function-template

In header view.h:

```
template<class S, template<typename> class V>
void Operate(S c, const V<S>& vx);

template<class T, template<typename> class U>
class ViewBase
{
    template<class S, template<typename> class V>
    friend void Operate(S c, const V<S>& vx);
};

template<class T>
class ViewTypeA : public ViewBase<T, ViewTypeA>
{

};

template<class T>
class ViewTypeB : public ViewBase<T, ViewTypeB>
{

};

template<class S, template<typename> class V>
void Operate(S c, const V<S>& vx)
{

}
```

In cpp:

```
#include "view.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Operate(5, ViewTypeA<int>());
    Operate(5, ViewTypeB<int>());
}
```

gcc (compiling with -std=gnu++11) gives errors:

```
Build: Debug in codeblocks (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)
main.cpp||In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:

main.cpp|7|error: call of overloaded ‘Operate(int, ViewTypeA&)’ is ambiguous

main.cpp|7|note: candidates are:

view.h|25|note: void Operate(S, const V&) [with S = int; V = ViewTypeA]

view.h|9|note: void Operate(S, const V&) [with S = int; V = ViewTypeA; T = int; U = ViewTypeA]
```

---

```
main.cpp|8|error: call of overloaded ‘Operate(int, ViewTypeB)’ is ambiguous

main.cpp|8|note: candidates are:

view.h|25|note: void Operate(S, const V&) [with S = int; V = ViewTypeB]

view.h|9|note: void Operate(S, const V&) [with S = int; V = ViewTypeB; T = int; U = ViewTypeA]
```

---

```
Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

### **Question:**

The class template parameters should not come into the picture at all - am I right? The ambiguity seems to be based on the template parameters of the class.

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Please note that I've edited my post to make it shorter.My question is

Comment: My question is: The class template parameters should not come into the picture at all - am I right. The ambiguity seems to be based on the template parameters of the class

Comment: By the way compiler version is 4.8.

Comment: Clang, Intel and Oracle all accept it, so please report to GCC's bugzilla.

Comment: @skm: The errors remain under gcc 4.9.0.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have filed in on gcc bugzilla:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61936